# Magento 1.8.1.0 dashboard life time sales is 0 after upgrading from 1.6.2

Tags: magento, dashboard

I upgrade my magento site to 1.8.1.0, but my admin dashboard not working correclty.
Lifetime Sales, Average Orders, and graph is not working. 0 and 'No Data Found'

Any one can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you haven't upgraded your site successfully.
I recommend you to upgrade to latest version.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/upgrading_magento

And your dashboard graphs that show the number of orders and the turn over aren’t working all you need to do it to go to the following location:

\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\dashboard\graph.phtml

Then find this code:

```
<img src="getChartUrl(false) ?>" alt="chart" title="chart" />
```

Modify it to the following code:

```
<img src="getChartUrl(true) ?>" alt="chart" title="chart" />
```

Refresh your page.